# Parsing string in android from django

Tags: android, django, eclipse

I am just trying to check strings sent from android in django 
and then a response is sent from django as a string back to android 
this code is working when i check it on my web browser but not on the android app
This is django django view code :

```
def login(request):
form = LoginForm(request.POST)
if request.method=='POST':
    uid=request.POST['uid']
    name=request.POST['name']
    if name=="ajinkya" :
        if uid=='11111':
            return HttpResponse("You are logged in...Thanks", content_type="text")

return render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I m trying to parse the string sent from django in android

my android app code is :

```
public class UploaddemoActivity extends Activity {
    public String strUID;
    public String strname; 
    public String string_response;
    InputStream inputStream;
    public String url;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText UID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UID);
        UID.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && 
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) { 
        strUID = UID.getText().toString(); 
                return true;
                } 
                return false;
                } 
                }); 

        final EditText nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_Nickname);
        nameText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 
               public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && 
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) { 
        strname = nameText.getText().toString(); 
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
            } 
            });    


    Button button;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> vars = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            vars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid",strUID));
            vars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",strname));
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                url="http://192.168.1.2/mysite/login/";
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(vars));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                Toast.makeText(UploaddemoActivity.this, "Response " + string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(UploaddemoActivity.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }
        }
    });


}


public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
        String res = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
    Toast.makeText(UploaddemoActivity.this, "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (contentLength < 0){}
    else{
        byte[] data = new byte[512];
        int len = 0;
        try{
            while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
            {
                buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer
            }
            }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        try{
            inputStream.close(); // closing the stream
            }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string
    Toast.makeText(UploaddemoActivity.this, "Result : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return res;
    }
```

}

this is just giving me reponse -1 and not the string which i sent in django

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response){
    return  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity();
}
```

Comment: can anyone help me please....how to parse json object or string in android passed from django?????? have tried many things but still not getting